# Correctly display photo/image in Twig

Tags: symfony, twig

I would like to display image instead of filename in Symfony2.My images lives inside web/uploads/images.With the code below provided by Symfony docs, I can successfully upload a file in a form, and display it in template.

```
protected function getUploadDir()
{
    return 'uploads/images';
}
protected function getUploadRootDir()
{
    return __DIR__.'/../../../../web/'.$this->getUploadDir();
}
public function getWebPath()
{
    return null === $this->photo ? null : $this->getUploadDir().'/'.$this->photo;
}

public function getAbsolutePath()
{
    return null === $this->photo ? null : $this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$this->photo;
}
```

so instead of

```
<td>{{ entity.photo }}</td>
```

displays

```
Photo | beard_1ap68nk-1ap68o8.jpg
```

inside my templates, what is the correct way to display those images instead of file name?

Comment: try <td><img src ="{{ entity.webPath}}"></td>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.This should work

```
<td><img src="/uploads/images{{ entity.photo }}" /></td>
```

Comment: don't hard code your webpath in every twig template, is better incapsulate it in a single point as the entity itself